# Find out recently played file in windows media player

Tags: windows-7, windows-media-player

Let's suppose I've a directory with some media files. I add them to the Windows Media Player playlist and then turn the *Shuffle* option to **ON**. The music starts playing and I leave the window minimized.

A few minutes later, when a file finishes playing, I want to see which file it was that had been playing. Is there a recent files history in WMP? I use Windows 7 Ultimate and WMP version 12.0.7601.1754.

Answer (score 2):

There's no built-in recent file history in WMP, but you can easily create one yourself by using WMP's Auto Playlist functionality.

In WMP's library, click the arrow next to `Create playlist` and select `Create auto playlist`. Enter a name for the playlist, and under `Music in my library`, add the condition `Date Last Played`. Then further customize the condition so that it reads `Date Last Played Is More Recent Than Yesterday`. Click `OK` to create the auto playlist.

Answer (score 1):

1. Click on Music.
2. Right-click on the column headings.
3. Click "Choose Columns...".
4. Tick "Date last played".

[image]